Angular & Firebase Hosting: Font Loading Issue in Firefox for Missing i18n "en" Locale
I use Angular in combination with Firebase Hosting to host my website, which supports multiple i18n locales.
Everything works fine in modern web browsers except for Firefox, where I encounter a strange issue: the browser fails to load a font.
The following error appears in the Firefox console:
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Roboto" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: http://localhost:5000/assets/fonts/roboto_regular.woff2 

Observations

This issue only occurs if the locale en does not exist. When I also generate a locale for en, everything works fine in Firefox as well. It also doesn't matter if I have just one locale or several, the only important thing is that the en locale exists.

Without the en locale, when I try to directly access the font's path, Firefox redirects me back to the default path (in my case, /de/). However, when the en locale is added, Firefox downloads the font directly without any issues. Note that in both cases, the path to the font didn't contain a locale-id.


Possible Causes

The issue seems to be related to how Firebase Hosting or Angular handles locale-specific routes and serves assets.
Firefox might reject the font because it is being redirected or served incorrectly when the "en" locale is missing.


As a temporary solution, i'm also hosting the en route, even though it is not being used.

Below are additional information that may be relevant.
Angular version is 19.0.5

firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "app-name",
    "public": "dist/app-name/browser",
    "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "*.[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f].+(css|js)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/@(ngsw-worker.js|ngsw.json)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/de/**",
        "destination": "/de/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/de/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "i18n": {
      "root": "/"
    }
  }
}

angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app-name": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": {
              "base": "dist/app-name"
            },
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/style/global-styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "ssr": false,
            "localize": true,
            "serviceWorker": "ngsw-config.json",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "."
              ]
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "serviceWorker": "ngsw-config.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "localize": [
                "de"
              ],
              "baseHref": "/"
            },
            "de": {
              "localize": [
                "de"
              ],
              "baseHref": "/de/"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "app-name:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "app-name:build:development"
            },
            "de": {
              "buildTarget": "app-name:build:de"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "app-name:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/style/global-styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      },
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "de"
      }
    }
  }
}

font in scss
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-display: swap;
    src:
        url("/assets/fonts/roboto_light.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("/assets/fonts/roboto_light.woff") format("woff");
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC,
        U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

